# Perl - Roundrobin through hash of arrays

Tags: perl, loops, round-robin

```
my %aggrs_by_node = (
    node1 => ['a1_1','a1_2'],
    node2 => ['a2_1','a2_2','a2_3'],
    hello => ['ah_1','ah_2','ah_3'],
    node3 => ['a3_1','a3_2','a3_3','a3_4'],
);
```

Anyone have any suggestions for how I could round-robin through all the arrays elements in this hash while avoiding the key `hello`?

```
Iteration 1 = a1_1
Iteration 2 = a2_1
Iteration 3 = a3_1
Iteration 4 = a1_2
Iteration 5 = a2_2
Iteration 6 = a3_2
Iteration 7 = a1_1
Iteration 8 = a2_3
```

etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This short program does what you ask. It keeps a hash of indices into each array.

I have used a separate sorted list of the hash keys in array `@keys` because taking them directly from the hash will result in an unpredictable order, and it looks like you need the output in a specific order.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %aggrs_by_node = (
  node1 => ['a1_1','a1_2'],
  node2 => ['a2_1','a2_2','a2_3'],
  hello => ['ah_1','ah_2','ah_3'],
  node3 => ['a3_1','a3_2','a3_3','a3_4'],
);

my %indices = map { $_ => 0 } keys %aggrs_by_node;
delete $indices{hello};
my @keys = sort keys %indices;

for my $iter (1 .. 20) {
  my $key = $keys[($iter - 1) % @keys];
  my $val = $aggrs_by_node{$key}[$indices{$key}];
  $indices{$key} = ($indices{$key} + 1) % @{ $aggrs_by_node{$key} };
  printf "Iteration %d = %s\n", $iter, $val;
}
```

**output**

```
Iteration  1 = a1_1
Iteration  2 = a2_1
Iteration  3 = a3_1
Iteration  4 = a1_2
Iteration  5 = a2_2
Iteration  6 = a3_2
Iteration  7 = a1_1
Iteration  8 = a2_3
Iteration  9 = a3_3
Iteration 10 = a1_2
Iteration 11 = a2_1
Iteration 12 = a3_4
Iteration 13 = a1_1
Iteration 14 = a2_2
Iteration 15 = a3_1
Iteration 16 = a1_2
Iteration 17 = a2_3
Iteration 18 = a3_2
Iteration 19 = a1_1
Iteration 20 = a2_1
```